# How can I create a patch for a contrib module or core which is not in version control?

Tags: 8

Because we use a devOps system that installs packages on the server via Composer, my core drupal installation and contrib modules are not in version control (Git).

I used to patch modules as follows:

- Commit everything, so my branch is up-to-date.
- Make my changes to the module (= write the fixes in the module).
- Inside my code editor go to Code -> Create patch and follow the steps there (because of Git, my editor knows what has changed).
- My patch gets saved where I prefer to do it.

Since we started working with keeping modules and core out of Git I do not have a clue on how to create my patches anymore.

Curious about the solutions you might have!

Comment: See https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches for the approved method.

Comment: It is not about how to apply it, but about how to create it (edited my question)

Comment: Follow the [Making a Drupal patch with GIt](https://www.drupal.org/node/707484) documentation on d.o for how to create patches.

Comment: @StefVanLooveren The answer is basically “however you want/can”, there’s no standardised process for doing something like what you’re describing. If this was forced on me I’d probably cobble together a couple of bash scripts that make copies of the site then run `diff` on them when required to. But it would be painful. Thing is, everything you’re talking about (Drupal and its contrib modules) lives in git already. So, arguably, you should create your patches using git, and make them available to your Composer workflow separately for installation

Comment: Just have the code you wanna create patch from. Then `git init`, then `git add .`, then `git commit -m "clean tree` to have a clean working tree, then make your code changes, finally do `git diff > my-patch.patch`, done. Delete the repo and continue your work.

Comment: If the patch fixes an issue with a contrib module, then I always add or update a relevant ticket and upload the patch so it is available to others. The process is well documented on drupal.org.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So, you would have to download the module seperately, like:

```
git clone --branch 8.1.x http://git.drupal.org/project/colorbox.git
```

Then, you make the change and run the following:

```
git diff 8.1.x > colorbox-css-issue.patch
```

This creates a patch for this module. Now you can place the patch in a patches folder and add it to your composer.json file.
Source: [This blogpost](https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/how-create-patch-drupal-module-not-version-control)

**Update**: created a small tutorial in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXCK4XPF6E0)

Comment: +1 upvote this answer (and the question) - this answer explains how to do it so simply and clearly. Helped me a lot, creating my patch for extending a contrib module.  I'm also grateful for the docs on drupal.org but they can be verbose and not as easy to read as on here, Thank you!